# How to get multiple text nodes as multiple lines inside a P

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to reproduce a contenteditable div like the [Disqus](https://about.disqus.com/disqus-demo-page) comment box.

They use a contenteditable `div` with a single `<p>` inside of it. The `<p>` is set with `white-space: pre-wrap`.

Their `<p>` tag with multiple lines looks like this, when inspected on Chrome:

[image: Multiline p 1]

[Disqus Exemple (go to comments section on this link and inspect the comment box)](https://about.disqus.com/disqus-demo-page)

After some research I found that the double-quotes indicates multiple text nodes, so I tried:

```
const text1 = document.createTextNode('123');
    const text2 = document.createTextNode('456');
    const text3 = document.createTextNode('789');

    root.childNodes[0].appendChild(text1);
    root.childNodes[0].appendChild(text2);
    root.childNodes[0].appendChild(text3);
```

Now I get this, which is similar when inspected, but they show as a single line instead of multiple:

[image]

[image]

**SNIPPET WITH EXAMPLE**

How to get '123' '456' '789' in multiple lines?

```js
const root = document.getElementById('root');
const p = document.getElementById('p1');

const text1 = document.createTextNode('123');
const text2 = document.createTextNode('456');
const text3 = document.createTextNode('789');

function handleClick() {
  p.appendChild(text1);
  p.appendChild(text2);
  p.appendChild(text3);
}
```

```css
#root {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="root" contenteditable="true" onClick>
<p id="p1">a</p>
</div>
<button onclick="handleClick()">Click</button>
```

Comment: You can use `p.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))` after each `TextNode` to insert new lines.

Comment: Thanks. That works as far as separating the lines. But it shows a `<br>` tag between the text nodes. How do you explain the Disqus? That only shows `text` nodes when inspected and renders multiple lines?

Answer (score 0):

Add new line character at to the end of each TextNode. The below code should work.

```
const lineBreak='\n';

const root = document.getElementById('root');
const p = document.getElementById('p1');

const text1 = document.createTextNode('123') + lineBreak;
const text2 = document.createTextNode('456') + lineBreak;
const text3 = document.createTextNode('789') + lineBreak;

function handleClick() {
  p.appendChild(text1);
  p.appendChild(text2);
  p.appendChild(text3);
}
```